# Extracting coordinates of segments in raster from TIFF image?

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, coordinates

I'm working with the attached tiff file and I am trying to extract the xy coordinates of the green lines.

so far I saved the image as raster stack, and this specific image is from a layer of that raster

`file_path <- "MyCells.tiff" 
rs <- stack(file_path) 
plot(rs[[2]])`

however, I don't know how to extract specifically those green lines. I trid to follow these two questions:

- [Extracting value of raster with coordinates using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279079/extract-value-of-a-raster-with-coordinates)
- [Extracting GeoTIFF data with coordinates using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302986/extract-raster-data-with-coordinates)

but I couldn't find an answer to my question. google sends me to image manipulation files.

[image: my_raster_layer_image]

Comment: There are no green lines. There are only green pixels. You can extract the green pixels but what then? Do you want to get the vector representation of the line network that seems to have generated the raster? After zooming in the data looks very noisy and conversion might be tricky.

Comment: yes, I agree with you, those are position of pixels. for the "what after" I need to calculate the distance of the yellow cells to the green segments. I think I found a solution tho, I edited my post to insert it.

Comment: A histogram on your raster should show two peaks for the green and yellow features if you want to work out the cut-off point for discriminating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I played around a little creating an sp objet

`rs <- raster(file_path, band=2)`

`sp <- SpatialPoints(rs)`

`res <- extract(rs, sp,
               fun=max,
               df=T,
               cellnumbers=F)`

then kept those with high intensity

`res <- res[res$All_Cells > 0.9,]`

`coord <- xyFromCell(rs, cell=res$ID)`

`plot(coord, cex=0.05, col="darkgreen")`

this actually gave me the coordinates of the green segments !!
[image: image_with_wanted_green_segments]

Comment: That looks like a very complex way of doing it! But well done for the effort! (Too many people on here don't bother trying).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that will give you the coordinates of each pixel that meets a criteria:

```
# Generate a raster to play with
library(raster)
library(RStoolbox)
mat = matrix(c(1,2,4,4),nrow=2,ncol=2)
ras=raster(mat)

# Use ggplot2::fortify() to turn it into a data.frame
ras.fort = ggplot2::fortify(ras)

# Select the raster values you're interested in (here, for example, 4)
mylocs = ras.fort[ras.fort$layer==4,]
# `x` and `y` columns are your coordinates
```

Comment: fortify() throws the following error, saying it doesn't take class RasterLayer? `rs <- raster(file_path)` 
`ras.fort <- fortify(rs)` 
`Error: data must be a data frame, or other object coercible by fortify(), not an S4 object with class RasterLayer`

Comment: Try loading the tif as a raster rather than a stack using `raster(file_path, band=2)`

Comment: nope, same error :-/

Comment: Oops - you need to load `library(RStoolbox)`

Comment: I think I was able to get it without using fortify but by creating an sp object and filtering the pixels with certain values :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to extract coordinates for the set of cells over the threshold:

```
> r = raster(matrix(runif(50*50),50,50))
> coords = coordinates(r)[r[]>0.9,]
```

This should show the raster with some dots on the greenest points:

```
> plot(r)
> points(coords)
```

[image]